# Architecture and querying in RedisGraph

Tags: graph, redis, cypher, redisgraph

I'm new to graphs, RedisGraph and Cypher and this took me a few hours without solving.

I have users paying other users.
A payment can be deposited from a user.
Some other user can eventually withdraw that deposit, but a deposit can also never be withdrawn.

I ended up with this:

```
(u:User)-[d:Deposit]->[t:Transaction]<-[w:Withdrawal]-(u:User)
```

Howerver at some point I need to find the transactions that have no Withdrawal.

My 2 questions:

- what would be a better architecture?
- even though you have a better logic, what is the way to retrieve nodes without the Withdrawal edge in the example?

Help will be very much appreciated! ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what would be a better architecture?

I believe you refer to what is called "graph modelling". Graph modelling in the basic form consists out of deriving entities and verbs out of sentences

- entities -> candidate labels
- verbs -> candidate relationship types

> A payment can be deposited from a user. Some other user can eventually
> withdraw that deposit,

- entities: Payment/Deposit/Transaction (I assume you use this interchangeably) and User
- verbs: deposit and withdraw

So you did a good job nailing that.

With regards to your second question. Given two transactions

```
(u1:User {uid:1})-[:Deposit]->(t1:Transaction {tid:1})<-[:Withdrawal]-(u3:User {uid:3})
(u2:User {uid:2})-[:Deposit]->(t2:Transaction {tid:2})
```

```
redis:6379> GRAPH.QUERY g "MERGE (u1:User {uid:1})-[:Deposit]->(t1:Transaction {tid:1})<-[:Withdrawal]-(u3:User {uid:3}) MERGE (u2:User {uid:2})-[:Deposit]->(t2:Transaction {tid:2})"
1) 1) "Labels added: 2"
   2) "Nodes created: 5"
   3) "Properties set: 5"
   4) "Relationships created: 3"
   5) "Cached execution: 0"
   6) "Query internal execution time: 1.920000 milliseconds"
```

You can add a `WHERE NOT` clause at query time

```
MATCH (u:User)-[d:Deposit]->(t:Transaction)
WHERE NOT ((t)<-[:Withdrawal]-())
RETURN u.uid
```

Which should only return the user with uid 2

```
redis:6379> GRAPH.QUERY g "MATCH (u:User)-[d:Deposit]->(t:Transaction) WHERE NOT ((t)<-[:Withdrawal]-()) RETURN u.uid"
1) 1) "u.uid"
2) 1) 1) (integer) 2
3) 1) "Cached execution: 0"
   2) "Query internal execution time: 0.816100 milliseconds"
```